# Rubber bands and Hooke's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity

Why does increasing the width of a rubber band increase its elastic constant($k$)? And why are the two variables directly proportional? Explain it in terms of the structure of the band, if that is relevant.

Comment: Should this be tagged as 'homework'? The way you phrase the question makes it sound like you copied it straight from an assignment. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Take a rubber band. Stretch it by a distance $x$ with your hands. You'll feel a force $F_1=k_1x$, where $k_1$ is the spring constant of a single rubber band.

Now take two rubber bands, and hold them side by side. Stretch it by a distance $x$ with your hands. Since you're stretching two of them, you'll feel twice the force, so $$F_2=2F_1=2k_1x=k_2x$$
where $k_2=2k_1$ is the spring constant of the two bands.

Hence $k$ is proportional to band thickness.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the width by a factor of two is the same as adding a second rubber band parallel to the first.  For each, $\Delta F=-k\Delta x$.  To stretch the combined system a distance $\Delta x$, you have to apply a force $F$ to the first, and $F$ to the second, doubling the needed force.  Thus, for the combined system you have $\Delta F_\mathrm{combined} = -2k\Delta x$.  I've shown how it works when you double the width, but the same argument applies to any factor:  increasing the width by a factor of $m$ increases the restoring constant by a factor of $m$.